# Template type deduction and type traits

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, type-traits

I am not able to figure out why following code does not compile. In the **overload 1**, the type deduced is `int &` so, it should result in SFINAE. And we should only have one candidate function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, std::remove_reference_t<T>>::value, void> foo(T&& a){
  std::cout << "overload 1" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void foo(T&& a){
  std::cout << std::is_same<T, std::remove_reference_t<T>>::value << std::endl;
  std::cout << "overload 2" << std::endl;
}

int main(){
  int a = 2;
  foo(a);
  // std::cout << std::is_same<int, int&>::value << std::endl;  ---> gives false
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation Error:

```
template_with_reference.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
template_with_reference.cpp:19:8: error: call of overloaded ‘foo(int&)’ is ambiguous
   foo(a);
        ^
template_with_reference.cpp:5:74: note: candidate: std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, typename std::remove_reference< <template-parameter-1-1> >::type>::value, void> foo(T&&) [with T = int&; typename std::remove_reference< <template-parameter-1-1> >::type = int]
 std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, std::remove_reference_t<T>>::value, void> foo(T&& a){
                                                                          ^~~
template_with_reference.cpp:11:6: note: candidate: void foo(T&&) [with T = int&]
```

Could you guys help me find the error?

Comment: Because you used `enable_if` instead of `enable_if_t`.

Comment: Oh, how did I miss that.  @Holt Thank you very much for such a quick reply.